# Why is this 304 response not updating the freshness of the locally cached resource?

Tags: http, caching, dotnet-httpclient

When I do a conditional GET and get a 304 response with a Cache-Control max-age header, I expect the freshness of the resource to be updated and future requests to get the representation from the local cache, assuming it is fresh.  However, I cannot get this to work using HttpClient.

This is my reproduction, as a simple .net 4.5 Console application using the Nuget dependencies `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` and `Microsoft.Net.Http`.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Cache;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;

namespace TestEtag
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Run as administrator to allow web server to start.
            // Clear browser cache to see initial 200 response when running multiple times

            var host = String.Format("http://{0}:8080/", Environment.MachineName);
            var server = WebApp.Start(host, app =>
            {
                var config = new HttpConfiguration();
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
                app.UseWebApi(config);
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Started Web server");


            var clientHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
            clientHandler.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.Default);
            var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(host) };

            var response = client.GetAsync("/resource").Result;  // Should return response
            Console.WriteLine("returned response " + response.StatusCode);
            var response2 = client.GetAsync("/resource").Result;  // Should get from local cache (and does)
            Console.WriteLine("returned response " + response2.StatusCode);

            Console.WriteLine("Pause for resource to expire");
            Thread.Sleep(7000);


            var response3 = client.GetAsync("/resource").Result;  // Should make conditional get and get 304 (and does)
            Console.WriteLine("returned response " + response3.StatusCode);

            var response4 = client.GetAsync("/resource").Result;  // Should get from local cache (but doesn't)
            Console.WriteLine("returned response " + response4.StatusCode);


            Console.ReadLine();
            server.Dispose();
        }


    }

    [Route("resource")]
    public class ResourceController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var etag = new EntityTagHeaderValue("\"XYZPQR\"");

            if (Request.Headers.IfNoneMatch != null)
            {
                if (Request.Headers.IfNoneMatch.Contains(etag))
                {
                    var notModifiedresponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
                    notModifiedresponse.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5) };
                    notModifiedresponse.Headers.ETag = etag;
                    return notModifiedresponse;
                }
            }
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("This is cached content with an etag")
            };
            response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5) };
            response.Headers.ETag = etag;

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that the last HTTP request should come directly from the local WinInet cache, however, you can see from fiddler it is making a network request and returning a 304.

Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

---

**Update**

I tried using Expires instead of Max-age but I get the same behaviour.  A subset of that trace shows the following,

```
System.Net.Cache Verbose: 0 : [15524] RequestCacheProtocol#2086040::GetRevalidateStatus(HttpWebRequest#10920143)
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [15524] StatusCode=304 NotModified System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [15524] ValidateResponse(), result = Continue.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [15524] After Response Cache Validation.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [15524] Updating headers on 304 response.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [15524] RevalidateCache(), result = ReturnCachedResponse.
System.Net.Cache Verbose: 0 : [15524] Exiting RequestCacheProtocol#2086040::GetRevalidateStatus()   -> result = ReturnCachedResponse
System.Net.Cache Verbose: 0 : [15524] RequestCacheProtocol#2086040::GetUpdateStatus()
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [15524] Response Status = NotModified.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [15524] Valid based on Status Code: 304.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [15524] Response==304 or Request was HEAD, updating cache entry.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [15524] Update Cached Headers.
```

As you can see, the log claims that the cache entry has been updated.

```
System.Net.Http Information: 0 : [15524] HttpClient#17533994 - Request for HttpRequestMessage#55917598 completed successfully. Returning response HttpResponseMessage#39055747: StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 18:12:18 GMT
  ETag: "XYZPQR"
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Age: 0
  Content-Length: 35
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 18:12:23 GMT }
```

The Expires date of this response shows 18:12:23.

The last request shows that the cached response is being found,

```
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] WinInetCache.Retrieve() -> Filename = C:\Users\darrel.TAVIS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\P6AEJQC4\resource[1].cache, Status = Success.
System.Net.Cache Verbose: 0 : [10644] Exiting WinInetCache.Retrieve()() Status = Success System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] ...Dumping Cache Context...
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] IsPrivateEntry   = True
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] IsPartialEntry   = False
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] StreamSize       = 35
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] Expires          = Tue, 07 Jan 2014 18:12:13 GMT
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] LastAccessed     = Tue, 07 Jan 2014 18:12:19 GMT
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] LastModified     = 
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] LastSynchronized = Tue, 07 Jan 2014 18:12:08 GMT
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] MaxStale(sec)    = 0
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] HitCount         = 4
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] UsageCount       = 2
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] EntryMetadata:
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] HTTP/1.1 200 OK System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] Content-Length: 35 System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] Date: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 18:12:08 GMT System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] Expires: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 18:12:13 GMT System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] ETag: "XYZPQR"
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] --- System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] SystemMetadata:
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] Entry Status Line = HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] Cache Cache-Control = .
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] [Now Time (UTC)] = Tue, 07 Jan 2014 18:12:19 GMT.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] [Age1] NowTime-Date Header = 11, Date Header: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 18:12:08 GMT.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] [MaxAge] Cache Expires - Date = 5, Expires: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 18:12:13 GMT.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] ValidateFreshness(), result = Stale.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] Cache Age = 11, Cache MaxAge = 5.
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] Request Condition = If-None-Match:"XYZPQR".
System.Net.Cache Information: 0 : [10644] ValidateCache(), result = Continue.
```

However, the Expires entry of the cache is still showing as 18:12:13 and not 18:12:23 from the 304 response.  The result is that the cached entry is deemed stale and we pay for the round trip back to the server to get another 304.

Comment: If you restart the program, you'll see 4 times a request and a `304` response. Perhaps the cache ignores the resource because of its repeated short lifespan?

Comment: @CodeCaster That's because the representation is persisted to disk in the WinInet cache.  If you don't clear the browser cache, the first request will be a conditional one, and from that point on, the freshness never gets updated.  This goes to the heart of my problem.  Using Etags ends up with worse performance than not using them.

Comment: Did you try enabling System.Net tracing to see if it sheds any light on why the response isn't being cached?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TheESJ I did.  I updated the question with the results from the log.